# How to solve a recurrence relation with two variables

Tags: recurrence-relations, recursion

I have the following recurrence relations

$$
\phi(i,j) = {1\over 4}\left( \phi(i-1,j) + \phi(i+1,j) + \phi(i, j-1) + \phi(i, j+1) \right)
$$

for

$$
i=1,\cdots, N-1, \,\text{and}\, j=1,\cdots , M-1
$$

with the initial conditions:

$$
\begin{align*}
\phi(0, j) &= a \\
\phi(N, j) &= b \\
\phi(i, 0) & = c \\
\phi(i, M) &= d \\
\end{align*}
$$

where intially $\phi = \phi_0 = \text{const}$ for the interior points.

Where

- $n, m, N, M \in \mathbb N $,
- $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb R $

I am trying to find a closed-form for this relation (that is an explicit expression for $\phi(i, j)$). I have only very basic knowledge about linear recurrence relation problems only. Unfortunately, in this, I have no idea how to start.

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Perhaps using generating functions may work? Did you try googling for an answer?

Comment: This looks awful a lot like what you would get if you were to solve the Poisson's problem in 2D using central finite differences.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas: No, that's not awful. This is mathematics, you have to think out of the box.

Comment: Hahaha, awful a lot is saying which means "a large amount". Also, I have been pondering for a while, how do you get $\phi(1,1)$ if you consider this as a recurrence relation? You can write this as a linear system, which would be the same linear system you obtain from 5-point stencil discretization of the Laplace's problem with the boundary conditions you give. So the closed form solution to this problem would be the closed form solution to the Laplace's problem. I think.

Comment: Thanks for the rabbit hole you sent me down. I couldn't gather enough for answer but here are my findings. You can write your recursion as a set of finite difference equations, $A\vec{\phi} = f$. The eigenvectors and the eigenvalues of this linear system of equations $A$ can be analytically found, so hypothetically, you can say $\vec{\phi}=VD^{-1}V^{-1}f$ and $\phi(i,j) = \vec{\phi}(i+nj)$. So you can find a closed form solution, question is "do you want to?"

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas: of course. I have edited the question to initialize the interior points

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas: I started that by descretizing the laplace equation using FD, the system of linear equations seems boring, so I thinked of something like a closed form would be better (or isn't it)

Comment: Can you give more context about what you are trying to do in your question? Are you trying to solve Laplace's problem using FD? In that case, the expected and the intended solution is to solve a linear system to find pointwise approximations to the exact solution. These approximations would converge to the exact solution as you add more points given the discretization is stable and consistent.

Comment: @AbdullahAliSivas: My goal is not to solve the Laplace equation iteratively. But I am looking for how to find a closed-form for such problems. Or, in general how can I solve two-variables recurrence relations.

Answer (score 1):

Focusing on an example with $N = 5, M = 4$ and making the formulations we obtain the set of equations

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
 -a-c+4 \phi _{1,1}-\phi _{1,2}-\phi _{2,1}=0 \\
 -c-\phi _{1,1}+4 \phi _{1,2}-\phi _{1,3}-\phi _{2,2}=0 \\
 -b-c-\phi _{1,2}+4 \phi _{1,3}-\phi _{2,3} =0\\
 -a-\phi _{1,1}+4 \phi _{2,1}-\phi _{2,2}-\phi _{3,1}=0 \\
 -\phi _{1,2}-\phi _{2,1}+4 \phi _{2,2}-\phi _{2,3}-\phi _{3,2}=0 \\
 -b-\phi _{1,3}-\phi _{2,2}+4 \phi _{2,3}-\phi _{3,3} =0\\
 -a-\phi _{2,1}+4 \phi _{3,1}-\phi _{3,2}-\phi _{4,1} =0\\
 -\phi _{2,2}-\phi _{3,1}+4 \phi _{3,2}-\phi _{3,3}-\phi _{4,2}=0 \\
 -b-\phi _{2,3}-\phi _{3,2}+4 \phi _{3,3}-\phi _{4,3}=0 \\
 -a-d-\phi _{3,1}+4 \phi _{4,1}-\phi _{4,2}=0\\
 -d-\phi _{3,2}-\phi _{4,1}+4 \phi _{4,2}-\phi _{4,3} =0\\
 -b-d-\phi _{3,3}-\phi _{4,2}+4 \phi _{4,3}=0 \\
\end{array}
\right.
$$

thus generating the linear system

$M\phi = B$ with

$$
M = \left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccccc}
 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 4 & 1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & 0 & 4 & -1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 & -1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 & -1 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right),\ \ \ B = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
 a+c \\
 c \\
 b+c \\
 a \\
 0 \\
 b \\
 a \\
 0 \\
 b \\
 a+d \\
 d \\
 b+d \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

and

$$
\phi = \left\{\phi _{1,1},\phi _{1,2},\phi _{1,3},\phi _{2,1},\phi _{2,2},\phi _{2,3},\phi
   _{3,1},\phi _{3,2},\phi _{3,3},\phi _{4,1},\phi _{4,2},\phi _{4,3}\right\}
$$

Making now $a=-1,b=1,c=1,d=-1$ we obtain fot $N=40, M=50$ the solution represented as follows

[image]

Follows a MATHEMATICA script which generates the graphics.

```
Remove["Global`*"]
n = 40;
m = 50;
equ[i_, j_] := 4 Subscript[phi, i, j] - ( Subscript[phi, i - 1, j] + Subscript[phi, i + 1, j] + Subscript[phi, i, j - 1] + Subscript[phi, i, j + 1])
equs = Flatten[Table[equ[i, j], {i, 1, n - 1}, {j, 1, m - 1}]];
Phi = Table[Subscript[phi, i, j], {i, 0, n}, {j, 0, m}];
For[i = 0, i <= n, i++, Subscript[phi, i, 0] = a; Subscript[phi, i, m] = b];
For[j = 1, j <= m, j++, Subscript[phi, 0, j] = c; Subscript[phi, n, j] = d];
vars = Flatten[Take[Phi, {2, n}, {2, m}]];
B = equs /. Thread[vars -> 0];
M = Grad[equs, vars];
parms = {a -> -1, b -> 1, c -> 1, d -> -1};
B0 = B /. parms;
solphi = LinearSolve[M, -B0];
MatrixPlot[Phi /. parms /. Thread[vars -> solphi]]
```

NOTE

With the characteristic function technique we could start as follows.

Calling

$$
S(x,y) = \sum _{j=0}^m \left(\sum _{i=0}^n x^i y^j
   a_{i,j}\right)
$$

and having in mind

$$
\sum _{j=0}^m \left(\sum _{i=1}^n x^i y^j a_{i-1,j}\right)=x \left(\sum _{j=0}^m \left(\sum _{i=0}^n x^i y^j
   a_{i,j}\right)-\sum _{j=0}^m y^j x^n a_{n,j}\right)\\
\sum _{j=0}^m \left(\sum _{i=0}^{n-1} x^i y^j a_{i+1,j}\right)=\frac 1x\left(\sum _{j=0}^m \left(\sum _{i=0}^n x^i y^j
   a_{i,j}\right)-\sum _{j=0}^m y^j a_{0,j}\right)\\
\sum _{j=1}^m \left(\sum _{i=0}^n x^i y^j a_{i,j-1}\right)=y \left(\sum _{j=0}^m \left(\sum _{i=0}^n x^i y^j
   a_{i,j}\right)-\sum _{i=0}^n x^i y^m a_{i,m}\right)\\
\sum _{j=0}^{m-1} \left(\sum _{i=0}^n x^i y^j a_{i,j+1}\right)=\frac 1y\left(\sum _{j=0}^m \left(\sum _{i=0}^n x^i y^j
   a_{i,j}\right)-\sum _{i=0}^n x^i a_{i,0}\right)
$$

we can find

$$
S(x,y) = \frac{x y}{x^2y+x y^2-4x y+x+y}\left(\left(a x^{n+1}+\frac bx\right)\sum_{j=0}^m y^j+\left(c y^{m+1}+\frac dy\right)\sum _{i=0}^n x^i\right)
$$

Comment: What is $S(x,y)$? how can I get an expression for $\phi(i,j)$?

Comment: $S(x,y)$ is the generating function and $\phi(i,j)\equiv a_{i,j}$

Comment: How can I find $a_{i,j}$ from $S(x,y)$?

Comment: Expanding $S(x,y)$ into the  form $\sum_i\sum_j a_{i,j}x^i y^j$

Comment: Due to how complicated the characteristic function technique is, we offer a more direct attack on the problem.

Comment: Thank you, before diving to understand this answer, I have a question about your previous answer. Given the generating function, why not use Taylor expansions to find the n'th coefficient? Here is [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3482153/the-nth-term-of-a-generating-function-for-a-recurrence-relation)

Comment: Yes. You can do that. Normally we can try to find a closed form and this can be complicated, instead a number but a number is completely acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

We can redefine $\phi(i,j)$ as $\varphi((M+1)i+j)$ to get the new recurrence:

$$4\varphi(n)=\varphi(n-M-1)+\varphi(n-1)+\varphi(n+1)+\varphi(n+M+1)$$

with initial conditions given by

$$\varphi(j)=a,~\varphi((M+1)N+j)=b,~\varphi((M+1)i)=c,~\varphi((M+1)i+M)=d$$

and $\varphi(n)=0$ at the "corners", where we restrict $j\le M$ and $i\le N$.

This can then be tackled as you would a one-dimensional linear recurrence using matrices.