# The $n$th term of a generating function for a recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions

I just started learning how to use generating functions to solve a recurrence relation. But I have some questions.

Suppose that I have a recurrence relation that has the rational function:

$$f(x) = \dfrac{P(x)}{Q(x)} $$

As far I know, I have to find the $n$th term of the generating function.

My question is:

Is it true to simply calculate the $n$th coefficient of the Taylor series of $f(x)$ ?

For example I asked a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59414420/how-to-find-the-nth-term-of-a-generating-function-using-sympy/59415209?noredirect=1#comment105018897_59415209). How can I use that to solve the recurrence relation?

**edit**: Just to clarify: Using some CAS package, like, Sympy is it sufficient to find the $n$th coefficient of the Taylor series without decomposing the function $f(x)$ to partial fractions?

Comment: You should probably use partial fraction decomposition to write $f(x)$ in terms of series you recognize (such as factors of $\frac1{1-x}$, $\frac1{(1-x)^2}$), etc. and go from there.

Comment: For your first question: "Yes".  (That's why people make such a fuss about  generating functions.)

Comment: @Math1000: I mean using a CAS system not manually.

Comment: Oh, well in that case why don't you try e.g. ```SeriesCoefficient``` in Mathematica?